# Is there a way to open multiple files at once from vim?

Tags: vim

When launching vim from the command line, I can do for example `vim *.txt` to open all text files in a directory at once.

For some reason, trying the same from inside vim ( `:e *.txt` ) gives an error: `E77: Too many file names`.

Is there a reason why vim refuses to open multiple at once? Is there a way to change that?

Comment: I use buffers for multiple files, no need to answer about tabs or split. Sorry, should have mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This should work  :

```
:next *.txt
```

Comment: Done! I couldn't do it yet when I posted my comment.

Comment: If you want to include files in all sub-directories in addition to files in the current directory, use `:n **/*.txt`

Comment: Wonderful!!! I've been looking for this cmd for too long.  I do have to say though ":next" is very unintuitive, would be much better to have ":e[dit] *txt" instead!

Comment: @mrk Exactly. Opening multiple files is an obvious thing to want to do, so :e should have allowed for that.  ":[count]n[ext] [++opt] [+cmd]" means "Edit [count] next file" Er, ok mate, if you say so!

Answer (score 14):

It's done in two operations.

Open all `*.js` files in as many vertical splits:

```
:argadd *.js
:argdo vs
```

in horizontal splits:

```
:argdo sp
```

in tabs:

```
:argdo tabe
```

Comment: I did the horizontal splits version and it did open all files in the dir, but it created four splits for each file.

Answer (score 1):

`:args *.txt` also works.

If it helps there is more information on this topic at `:help argument-list`
and `:help 07.2`. Both of those sections help explain how to use the argument list and how the buffer list is not the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

Also, to add to the other answers, when you first start vim you can open multiple files at the same time, e.g.:

```
vim *.txt
```

Comment: That's what OP tried, but he had the error: `E77: Too many file names`.

Comment: @kenorb No, that works fine, it was `:e *.txt` that gave errors. The real problem with this is that it doesn't work when vim is already running.

Comment: That's literally mentioned the first line of the question.